# C# RegEx for Numbers up to 100

Tags: c#, regex

I created a regex to match numbers from 1-100, including decimals such as 50.25

For some reason, decimal numbers are not matching and I have no idea why.

Can someone help?

```
string pattern = @"^([1-9][0-9]{0,1}(\\.[\\d]{1,2})?|100)$";
Regex r = new Regex(pattern);
Match m = r.Match(s.SearchRadius);
if (!m.Success)
{
    s.SearchRadius = "20";
}
```

Comment: It's working for me, http://rubular.com/r/CCYpnCHBoc

Comment: I think you want \. and \d, not \\. and \\d

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're using the `@` sign on your string, so you shouldn't escape \ characters.

All you need is

```
string pattern = @"^([1-9][0-9]{0,1}(\.[\d]{1,2})?|100)$";
```

Answer (score 4):

When using `@""` string literals, you don't escape backslashes.  You probably intended for `\.` and `\d`

```
@"^([1-9][0-9]{0,1}(\.[\d]{1,2})?|100)$";
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to play devils advocate - the non-regex solution is:

```
double d;
if (!(double.TryParse(s.SearchRadius, out d) && d <= 100 && d >= 0))
{
    s.SearchRadius = "20";
}
```

And for good measure that famous quote by Jamie Zawinski:

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use
>   regular expressions." Now they have two problems.

Answer (score 0):

Your code catches both the number xx.xx and .xx. If you want it to catch the number only once insert the ?: in the second parenthesis.

```
^([1-9][0-9]{0,1}(?:\.[\d]{1,2})?|100)$
```

Btw, a good way to test regular expressions is a site like http://rubular.com/
where u can see the results right away.